# How can I prevent an iframe from accessing parent frame?

Tags: javascript, iframe, parent, same-origin-policy

I've got a page with an iframe. The page and the source of the iframe are in different domains. Inside the iframe I'm using a rich text editor called CuteEditor (which has turned out to be not so cute). There are certain javascript functions in CuteEditor which try to access 'document' but the browser denies access since they're not in the same domain.

Here's the exact error:

> Permission denied to access property 'document'
>   http://dd.byu.edu/plugins/cuteeditor_files/Scripts/Dialog/DialogHead.js
>   Line 1

Editing the javascript is out of the question because it's been minfied and obfuscated so all the variable names are cryptic.

Using a different editor is currently out of the question because this is a work project and this is the editor I've been told to use.

Is there a way to keep the iframe self-contained? So it does everything inside the iframe and doesn't try to break out to the parent frame?

Answer (score 11):

If the child iframe is loaded from a different domain, then it will not be able to access the parent page or DOM.

However, there is a still a possible vulnerability to man-in-the-middle attack as follows. Suppose your page loads off http://yoursite.com and the iframe goes to http://badsite.org

- first http://badsite.org redirects to http://yoursite.com/badpage
- This is the step that requires a man-in-the-middle attack. The attacker must either be able to get between the user and yoursite.com, or control the answers to your DNS lookup. This is easier than it sounds -- anyone who has administrative control over a public WiFi access point could do it (think Starbucks, hotels, airports.) The goal is to serve the content of http://yoursite.com/badpage from the attacker's site, not your actual site.
- The attacker can then serve whatever malicious code they like from the (fake)  http://yoursite.org/badpage. Because this is in the same domain as the main page, it will have access to the parent DOM.

The HTML5 iframe sandbox attribute seems to be the way to avoid this. You can read the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-sandbox), but the best description might be [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh563496.aspx).

This seems to be supported on [Chrome](http://blog.chromium.org/2010/05/security-in-depth-html5s-sandbox.html), [IE10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh563496.aspx), [FireFox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=341604), [Safari](http://www.apple.com/safari/features.html).

The spec says that if the "allow-same-origin" attribute is *not* set, "the content is treated as being from a unique origin." This should prevent your child iframe from accessing  any part of the parent's DOM, no matter what the browser thinks the URL is.

Comment: The attack is not so easy as stated. When the device gets address to yoursite.com from DNS, it will cache for further accesses. To fully implement this attack, an HTTP proxy is required, and the man-in-the-middle will have to rewrite the webpage to use http://yoursite.com/badpage as iframe src. This is further complicated if you use HTTPS, because the proxy would have to mimic HTTPS as HTTP in order to change pages. It's not impossible, but unless the site is attractive to attackers (like banks, auctions or hugely accessed sites that can be used to harvest passwords), your exposure is low.

Comment: That doesn't scenario seems far-fetched, unless you have evidence that *CuteEditor* is in fact an illegitimate product and a malicious script.

Comment: The attack here doesn't make much sense. If the attacker controls your DNS, they have a much simpler attack available to them: they can simply redirect your *original* page load on http://yoursite.com to their malicious server and run arbitrary malicious JavaScript code. If the attacker controls your DNS, the iframe is totally superfluous to anything the attacker might want to do.

Answer (score -6):

You shouldn't need to worry about that happening.

The only way iframes can talk cross-origin is with postMessage, and that's only possible if you're listening to that domain directly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage

Comment: Yet CuteEditor doesn't work inside the iframe because of this error. Is it a different problem, then?